# Metro App Customised ListView KeyDown event not firing

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a Metro application with a `ListView` that has this definition:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lvData" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Padding="4,0,0,0">
                                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=lvData, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                    </Grid>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

I have tried setting the `KeyDown` event on different controls embedded within this `ListView's` `DataTemplate`, but the event never seems to fire.

**NOTE:** If I double click the `ListViewItem`, then the `KeyDown` event is triggered.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your control needs to have focus to handle KeyDown events. If you need to handle them globally - you could handle them on `Window.Current.KeyDown` instead of the control.

Comment: Following your suggestion I have programmatically given it Focus and then attempted a key press to see if the KeyDown event is raised, but that hasn't helped. Is there something specific I need to do?

Comment: Check if your `Focus()` call actually succeeded. I think you need to set `IsTabStop` to `true` for a control to be focusable.

Comment: Hi Filip. That didn't help either. What does the DoubleTapped event do to the control that Tapped doesn't? Because on DoubleTapped everything works.

Comment: Found a control that was stealing Focus all the time, which is why the event wasn't being triggered. Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, it was the WebView control. See this article for workaround: http://blog.christopheargento.net/2013/02/07/winrt-trick-scrolling-and-webview-navigatetostring-bug/